# Automated Java to Kotlin conversion: unresolved reference to 'ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID'

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using [AppIntro](https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro) in my Kotlin app, and need to customize its layout. The tutorial tells us to use [this code](https://github.com/paolorotolo/AppIntro/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/amqtech/opensource/appintroexample/util/SampleSlide.java) as starting point. Because that's written in Java, I converted it to Kotlin (not 100% automated though, because Kotlin doesn't support 'static' keyword):

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.annotation.Nullable
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View


class IntroFragment: Fragment() {
    private val ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID = "layoutResId"
    private var layoutResId: Int = 0

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(layoutResId: Int): IntroFragment{
            val args: Bundle = Bundle()
            args.putSerializable(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID, layoutResId)
            val fragment = IntroFragment()
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(@Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (arguments != null && arguments!!.containsKey(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID)) {
            layoutResId = arguments!!.getInt(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID)
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, @Nullable container: ViewGroup?,
                              @Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(layoutResId, container, false)
    }
}
```

At this part:

```
 args.putSerializable(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID, layoutResId)
```

Android Studio complains:

> Unresolved reference: ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID` is an instance variable while your `newInstance` method is a class (static) method.

If you move `ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID` into the companion object, it will work. Like this:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.annotation.Nullable
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View


class IntroFragment: Fragment() {
    private var layoutResId: Int = 0

    companion object {
        private const val ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID = "layoutResId"

        fun newInstance(layoutResId: Int): IntroFragment {
            val args: Bundle = Bundle()
            args.putSerializable(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID, layoutResId)
            val fragment = IntroFragment()
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(@Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (arguments != null && arguments!!.containsKey(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID)) {
            layoutResId = arguments!!.getInt(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID)
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                              @Nullable container: ViewGroup?,
                              @Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(layoutResId, container, false)
    }
}
```

You could also make `ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID` a `const` like i've shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Move the field to your companion object:

```
companion object {

    private val ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID = "layoutResId"

    fun newInstance(layoutResId: Int): IntroFragment{
        val args: Bundle = Bundle()
        args.putSerializable(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID, layoutResId)
        val fragment = IntroFragment()
        fragment.arguments = args
        return fragment
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables and functions inside the `companion object` block are basically static (if you were to draw parallels from Java).

The `ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID` variable is not inside the `companion object` scope, so it can't be accessed statically.

Move the `ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID` variable inside the `companion object` scope, and all will be good again.